# jqGrid raises Load Error before receiving data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've got a jqGrid that is working fine, but I'm attempting to stop it from loading data on page load.  I followed other instructions of setting the datatype to 'local', creating the grid, and then using setGridParam afterwards.  However, after I change the grid parameters and call reloadGrid, I get a 'Load Error' even though no call ever hit the server.

```
function set_grid_params(){
    $("#current").setGridParam({postData:{emp:function(){return $("#employee").val();}}});
    $("#current").setGridParam({edit_url: #the api URL});
    $("#current").setGridParam({mtype:'GET', datatype:'json'});

    $("#current").trigger('reloadGrid');
}

#In main method
$("#current").jqGrid({
    name: "Current Balances",
    colNames: ["a","b","c"],
    colModel: [unimportant],
    datatype: 'local'
});

#do some other stuff to set $("#employee").  It is blank at page load,
# which is why I need to stop initial load, as the postData is empty.

set_grid_params();
```

The dialog that pops up says:

Load Error
-Type: parsererror
-Response: 200
-OK

I never stop at any breakpoints in my API method, and the server logs don't show that any requests hit the URL.  What am I missing?

Comment: You example use set `edit_url` parameter. Probably you want to set `url` parameter instead? By the way you can use *one* call of `setGridParam` with all properties which you need to set instead of calling the method three times.

Comment: Thanks, changing it to `url` was all it needed!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example sets `edit_url` parameter. Probably you want to set `url` parameter instead? By the way you can use one call of `setGridParam` to set all properties which you need to set at once instead of calling the method three times.